# DropDownList Close

Tags: combobox, drop-down-menu

I have an application that uses cascading dropdown lists for an easy 90% of the fields.  For some reason, and randomly, they'll close before the user can select an item.  This has been very frustrating, as you can imagine.  I use Windows 7 with Internet Explorer 9 to test changes once I've completed them and this never happens to me.  I can use the production environment without a problem.  However, once I launch XP IE8, the problem starts happening.  My question is, what can cause this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, C#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could possibly be that your browser is displaying the webpage in compatibility view. To disable compatibility view go to tools->compatibility view make sure compatibility view is unchecked.

You can also disable it in your code by placing the following code in your head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

You can read about compatibility mode at http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Make-older-programs-run-in-this-version-of-Windows

However, this is a random guess at what could be wrong. Without the code we can't be exactly sure.

Comment: Thanks, that was the first thing I thought of as well.  It didn't really do anything. Sorry about the lack of a code sample, but it's system wide.

Comment: Well, compatibility mode was the culprit. To be more exact, there's a setting called "Display intranet sites in Compatiblity View" that was checked on some browsers and not on others.  Another problem user was using Firefox with IETab, which for some inexplicable reason forces sites rendered with it into IE7 mode.  Once I changed it to Forced IE8 the problem went away.  The really strange this is that this wasn't a problem for the past 2 years the site has been in use. Does that line of code disable compatibility mode regardless of IE version?  Does it disable it in IETab for Firefox?

Comment: Well this line of code emulates whatever version of IE that you specify. I had the same problem, I had no idea why my site was being rendered into IE7 mode. From what I have read I am under the impression that it will disable compatibility mode for the specified IE version.

Check out MSDN's article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Without any code we cannot help you.
Could it be that the screen needs to be refreshed or repainted upon SelectedIndexChanged for the combo box ?

Comment: Thanks for the replay.  I'm not really sure whta the deal is.  Like I mentioned above, it's happening in IE8/Windows XP system wide.  It wasn't doing this prior to my last build.  I'm wondering if the CSS file might have something to do with it.